# Customer Community plus user can't access contact record on custom visualforce Page

Tags: community, sharing

I have Created a custom visualforce page . Which shows contact details.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
  <!-- Page Header -->
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Edit" subtitle="New Member" />

  <!-- Begin Form -->
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Rules" mode="edit">


      <!-- Fields -->
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" showHeader="true" title="Membership Status">
           <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Status__c}" required="true" />-->
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}" required="true" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"  required="true" />
         <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Likes_Ice_Cream__c}" />-->
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"     required="true" />
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel >Referrer</apex:outputLabel>
             <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Best_Friend__c}" /> -->
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <!-- Button Section -->
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add  Member" action="{!save}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <style>
    .logo {
      float: right;
      width: 60px;
      margin: -65px 20px 0 0;
    }
    .rules {
      color: red;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: Courier;      
      margin: 10px 0 10px 30px;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</apex:page>
```

I am seeing following error when i open this page from customer community plus user.

> Data Not Available The data you were trying to access could not be
>   found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system
>   error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it,
>   please look at our support page.

But i can see the contact record on salesforce UI with same CCP User.

Sharing setting for Contact : Controlled By Parent

Sharing Setting for Account : Public Read/Write

Is this Known Issue?

While , This page is accessible to community user

Comment: Does your community has a sub-domain, check if you are being redirected to a correct URL.

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you mean by sub-domain , i have checked the url , it seems correct

Comment: Is the above owd is for external access or internal access?

Comment: @Durgapaavank above owd is for external and internal both.

Comment: Is that contact is linked with Account?

Comment: @Ankuli yes , contact linked to Account